# Installing single OS Ubuntu 14.04 in EFI mode

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.04, system-installation, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Tohiba laptop from a iso image written to USB. The original OS was Windows 8, but when I was installing the Ubuntu, it said that no OS is detected. I did not care, as I wanted to completely remove the Windows and install single OS, Ubuntu.

Installation was smooth as usual, but there was a problem in creating the EFI boot. Now the system does not boot to Ubuntu. I tried Boot-Repair, but no success.

How can I freshly install ubuntu with a correct boot?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, disable Secure Boot on your computer. Then try preparing a CD-R or USB flash drive with my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) (Image files for both are available on its downloads page.) Boot to the rEFInd medium. You should see at least one option for a Linux kernel (with a name beginning with `vmlinuz`) in its menu. Try it. If it boots, install the Debian-package version of rEFInd (either downloaded and installed manually via `dpkg` or via the PPA described at the bottom of the rEFInd downloads page).

Comment: sorry, I didn't get. I have a ISO file of Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and the rEFInd flashdriver downloaded from the link you introduced. Now how can I make a bootable USB flash drive?